# PHP MySQL Where clause isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, database, where-clause

I have a database like which has multiple columns and when querying it with a `WHERE` clause it won't get any results.
Here is the code I am using :

```
$columns = $_GET['var'];
$where = $_GET['where'];
$checkValue = $_GET['checkValue'];
$userInput = $_GET['userInput'];

$query = "SELECT ";

foreach($columns as $val)
    $query .= "$val, ";

$query .= "FROM Email";

if($where === "yes")
    $query .= " WHERE $checkValue = '$userInput'";
```

`$columns` is multiple checkboxes for the user to select which columns they wish to see. It works perfectly except when adding the where clause. When I've been testing it I made sure that the it was exactly the same as in the database. Also the `$checkValue` is a dropdown list which values are exactly the same as in the database. Also just to note later on I edit the query so the last comma is removed.

To print it out I use :

```
while($c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    foreach($columns as $val){
        $header = ucwords($val);
        echo "<b>$header</b><br>";
        echo $c[$val]."<br>";   
    }
    echo "-------------------------------<br>";
}
```

This is the query that is outputted when not using the where clause and works:

```
 SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email
```

And here is the query that doesnt work:

```
 SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email WHERE mediatype = 'Blog'
```

Any advice?

EDIT:
Here is the table with:
[image: Db]

There is more columns but these are ones I want to focus on.

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens when you run this directly in MySQL?

Comment: please show your mysql table setup.
Also I'd recommend Using PDO and prepared statements.
This has epic injection potential.

Comment: It does the same and returns nothing, there isn't any error. Maybe something wrong with the sql?

Comment: Show the table data. Are you sure it should return any value?

Comment: You generate an extra comma (`,`) before the `FROM` keyword and the query doesn't run at all because it has this syntax error.

Comment: I remove the last comma with $lastComma = strrpos($query, ",", -1);
 $query = substr_replace($query, "",  $lastComma, 1);   Also it works fine when selecting multiple columns and outputs fine, its just as soon as I add the WHERE clause it wont work

Comment: First I just want to get it working then I'll focus on stopping SQL injections :)

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email WHERE mediatype LIKE 'Blog%'`? I'm thinking you have some trailing spaces or something in the data.

Comment: I've tried that before and still no results, I've also tried the '%Blog%' and still nothing

Comment: Well, how about: `SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email WHERE mediatype IS NOT NULL`? If that one doesn't pull back something, there's something wrong with the table.

Comment: Just tried that code and its returning results. Tried on both phpMyAdmin and put it in my code and it worked fine, maybe its whats being inputted?

Comment: I'm thinking there's something going on with the data in the column that's not working correctly. Have you tried `SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email WHERE mediatype = 'Unspecified'` and see if you get the expected results there?

Comment: I have tried that and nothing is returned

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, edit one of the rows with "Blog" in it, copy the entire cell value (control-A and control-C, don't highlight it with your mouse) and then do `SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email WHERE mediatype = '<paste what you copied here>'`. See what happens.

Comment: I tried that I control-A and C it and there was an empty line after it, I still pasted it in and returned nothing, maybe if I removed the line? This is how it looked SELECT date, mediatype FROM Email WHERE mediatype ='Blog '

Comment: That worked, I took away the extra line on one of the Blog and it returned the information, weird that the 'Blog%' didn't work then

Answer (score 1):

Your generate SQL request seems to have a syntax error. Just change the way you generate it.

Instead of

```
foreach($columns as $val)
  $query .= "$val, ";
```

Try

```
$query .= implode(', ' $columns);
```

That will skip the last comma.

Comment: Thanks, that is a much easier way than I was doing. However it still doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The blog column had an extra empty line that 'Blog%' wasn't working on. I went in the database and deleted the extra line and used the query again and it worked.

Thanks everyone for the help :)